# when I update rxjs from 6.3.3 to 6.4.0, I get the error:ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected

Tags: angular, rxjs

After updating to rxjs 6.4.0, I get the error:

> ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

The same code worked well on rxjs 6.3.3.

I recode like this is ok!

```js
return new Observable(subscriber => {
  this.codeReturn
    ? subscriber.next(this.codeReturn)
    : this.http.get<DataReturn>(codeUrl.getCode, { strLookUpTypeCode: code, strLanguage: lng }).pipe(
    tap(res => {
      this.codeReturn = res;
    }),
    ).subscribe(res => subscriber.next(res));
});
```

On rxjs 6.3.3 is ok, but rxjs 6.4.0 get error.

`this.http.get<DataReturn>()` is the reason why caused this happen, but the `defer` method of rxjs is different from 6.3.3 is important!

```js
 defer(() => this.codeReturn
      ? of(this.codeReturn)
      : this.http.get<DataReturn>(codeUrl.getCode, { strLookUpTypeCode: code, strLanguage: lng }).pipe(
        tap(res => {
          this.codeReturn = res;
        }),
      ));
```

Comment: If you only want to call a http request once and provide the returned value from a cache to all subsequent subscribers you can do so using `shareReplay(1)`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57377477/9423231

Comment: So you want to be using `defer()` or `new Observable()`? Because these are two different things.

Comment: I just only want to know how to make it work well when i use the defer method of rxjs in the 6.4.0